# preg_replace with two similar words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem with two very similar expressions in Slovak language. I'm trying to replace the expression for a html link, this is my example code below. I have about 90 words in the array.

```
// mysql query above.
for($i=1;$i<=$datas[1];$i++) {
  $regex[] = '/('.htmlentities($rows['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').')/i';
  $wrl[] = '<a href="'.URL.'link/'.urlencode($rows['alias']).'" class="underscored">'.strtolower($rows['title']).'</a>';
}
$content = preg_replace($regex, $wrl, $content);
```

But I have a problem with very similar words; (nenasytene mastne kyseliny, nasytene mastne kyseliny). preg_replace removes the **ne** from the longer word, which results in the word being linked to a wrong article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your regular expression to specify a word boundary `\b` before and after the phrase you want to replace with a link:

```
$regex[] = '/\b('.htmlentities($rows['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').')\b/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend and append your regex with `\W`:

```
$regex[] = '/\W('.htmlentities($rows['title'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').')\W/i';
```